# How to visualize json data input?

Tags: json, data-visualization

I have json file as follows:

```
{
      "status":"UP",
      "diskSpace":     {"status":"UP","total":63279460352,"free":6826328064,"threshold":10485760}
     .........

 }
```

Now, I want to visualize above json file in such a way so that I can have a look on what the status is, what the threshold is, and can get an alert or color change, if threshold crosses a limit. The file changes dynamically on a particular port.

Which library/tool would be better for the above?

Answer (score 1):

Make a class resembling your Json.
Example:

```
public class DiskSpace
{

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public long total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("free")]
    public long free { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("threshold")]
    public int threshold { get; set; }
}

public class HddInfo
{

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("diskSpace")]
    public DiskSpace diskSpace { get; set; }
}
```

Make any kind of visualization you want to.
Print in a console application, WPF application, Winforms application, UWP application.
It's up to you really - I would personally make a WPF application with [wpf-notifyicon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon).

Implement a backgroundtask that reads your Json every X seconds, deserializes it into an object of your class and update your GUI when it's done.
Example of making an object from a Json string using Newtonsofts Json.NET:

```
var HddInfo = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<HddInfo>(jsonText);
```

Scheduling Libraries that i know of: Quartz or FluentScheduler
(.Net framework should have something as well.)